# JAVA: Database resultset keep returning zero rows

Tags: java, database

i verified through the use of stubs that the driver is loading and the connection is being made. my method that queries the database is executing without errors but is returning an empty resultset of 5 columns and 0 rows (which i verified via debug). There are 4 records with 5 columns in the test database and my query asks to return all results. I may just be tired... any insight on what im missing? here is the query method. the database file is access .mdb

public ArrayList fillResults()
    {
        ArrayList savedData = new ArrayList();
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet results = null;

```
    try
    {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        results = stmt.executeQuery(SELECT_ALL);
        while(results.next())
        {
            for(short i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                savedData.add(results.getString(i));
            }
        }

    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage() + ": error during retrieval.");
    }
    finally
    {           
        try
        {
            results.close();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e){}
    }

    return savedData;
}
```

Comment: Please double check that you are using the correct database. How does the code look that iterates over the result set?

Comment: while(results.next())
   {
    for(short i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
     savedData.add(results.getString(i));
    }
   }

Comment: the first column has index 1, not 0

Comment: ive tried getString(i) and getString(i + 1). It doesnt change the fact that the resultset has 0 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should NOT be returning a `ResultSet`.   And a persistence class should not have a Swing `JOptionPane` in it.

Try it like this:

```
package persistence;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class JdbcDemo
{
    private static final String SELECT_SAVED_DATA = "select * from saveData";

    private Connection connection;

    public JdbcDemo(Connection connection)
    {
        this.connection = connection;
    }

    public List<String> getSavedData() throws SQLException
    {
        List<String> savedData = new ArrayList<String>();

        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try
        {
            stmt = this.connection.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(SELECT_SAVED_DATA);
            while (rs.next())
            {
                savedData.add(rs.getString(1)); // modify this as needed
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            DatabaseUtils.close(rs);
            DatabaseUtils.close(stmt);
        }

        return savedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: im still getting the same resultset, returns 5 columns 0 rows. just to check, i modified the query to return only 2 columns; then the resultset came back with 2 columns 0 rows. im lost

Comment: If you can log into the database using another client and see rows, then it says you aren't connecting to the database that you think you are.  Check your connection URL, and make sure that you can see rows with another client.  Check your assumptions - when they don't match what you think you should be getting, it says you're fooling yourself with false assumptions.

Comment: connection was fine. i scrapped and started over with what you posted and it worked. doesn't quite make sense to me. i tried again with sending a resultset back on the return just out of curiosity but that still didnt work. i dont get it. but i have it working now, nonthelist